# Kendo DropDownList making requests even when empty

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have the following code to create a DropDownList using Kendo UI in my ASP.Net MVC/Web API project, which is working except that when the DropDownList is empty and I click on it, it still makes a server request.

How can I prevent this?

```
<input data-role="dropdownlist"
    id="ute"
    data-auto-bind="true"
    data-text-field="Name"
    data-value-field="Id"
    data-cascade-from="unit"
    data-cascade-from-field="cascadeField"
    data-bind="value: filter.theFilter, source: theDataSource"
    data-option-label="TheLabel"
    data-index="0"
    style="width:300px;" />
```

Comment: The data behind the dropdownlist could have changed in the meantime. This is why it tries to refresh.

Comment: i'm using generally fluent builder, in there i'm preventing this `ServerOperation = false` flag. For this question you can use `data-server-operation = "false"` i think.

Comment: @OğuzhanSoykan: that's not a option on the kendo dropdown list.

Comment: Can you try ServerFiltering ?